# Why does this Javascript return undefined?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, dom-events, settimeout

```
var linksList = [
   "http://a.com",
   "http://b.com",
   "http://c.com",
]

for (var i=0; i<linksList.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(linksList[i]); 
    }, 3000);
}
```

I'm pasting this into Chrome inspector and it returns a number for whatever reason (it seems to be an entirely random number?)... then it waits... and then returns 3 'undefined' console errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use closure:

```
for (var i=0; i<linksList.length; i++) {
    (function(i){
       setTimeout(function() {
          console.log(linksList[i]); 
       }, 3000);
    })(i);
}
```

Your problem is ,when `setTimeout`'s callback is called, `i = linksList.length` already , so you are outputting:

```
 console.log(linksList[ linksList.length ]);
```

`3` times, where `linksList[ linksList.length ]` is `undefined`.

Comment: I thought it would be available because it was created not within the nested function? Hmmm. Thanks. I will have to read more I guess

Comment: Hmmm... it works now but it logs them all at the same time in console (at least there are no errors now. any idea?)

Comment: @Tallboy As all `setTimeout` functions are set  approximately at same time and with same delay (`3000ms`), the callbacks will be called approximately at same time. If you want some delay between callback calls, then specify different delays on `setTimeout` function. For example, with `setTimeout(function(){}, 3000*(i+1))`, callbacks will be called with `3000ms` delay.